# Unable to generate excel file on server

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to generate invoice with the following code.

It works fine in local-host ,

When i executed the code in my friends server , it worked fine,

where as same code fails to generate in my server - (using godaddy)

Do i need to modify any server settings?

```
 <?php
    include("includes/DbConfig.php");
    $SQL = "SELECT id,user_mobile,user_email FROM users limit 1,2";
    $header = '';
    $result ='';
    $exportData = mysql_query ($SQL ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

    $fields = mysql_num_fields ( $exportData );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysql_field_name( $exportData , $i ) . "\t";
    }

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $exportData ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value )
        {                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
            {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $result .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );

    if ( $result == "" )
    {
        $result = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
    }

        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        print "$header\n$result";
    ?>
```

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Have you had a look at the error logs?

Comment: i have checked the error log , no errors in it

Comment: How are you defining `TABLE_USERS`? Where is your constant definition?

Comment: Is that file included in the above PHP? I do not see the include.

Comment: yes its included....in my code...

Comment: Your previous comment says db_config.php, but you're showing DbConfig.php in the code. Which one is right? And you have changed your query from the original question. Stealth edits like that are *not cool*.

Comment: the code which i have edited is the correct one..
table is getting connected , and data is also getting echoed..correctly..from the table...
but the thing is excel is not getting generated...

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Do you know if you have the permission to write onto the server? It might be worth checking the directory of which you are writing to allows for it to happen.

Comment: i have kept the file in root its permission : 0644

Answer (score 1):

I just added ob_get_clean(); and it started working

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include("includes/DbConfig.php");
?>

   <?php
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$result";
    ?>
```